how to find application state in a system file in android
After use pm disable [package_name], where can we find a file store it's new state in Android system.
/data/system/packages.xml has no state or state code, but there is permission info.
my rooted mi8 is locked after i disable com.xiaomi.account. even though i type in correct password, it return "couldn't sign in (rpc error)"I hope to edit the file in recovery.
